# Can document root of the server be on client machine

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, git

Here is my problem.

In our company we have a setup like this. There is a server with apache, php and all. All the client (dev) machine has their one drive (M:) mapped to the home folder on the server of that user. We have also setup the Dynamic document root. For e.g. jimy.www.domain.com get the document root as /home/jimitm/www/. Now we have started using GIT some days back. One problem we are facing is `git status` (or any other similar command) take too much time as it has to check every file for the change on the network drive.
What I was thinking is that at all possible that the document root would on client(dev) machine D: Drive (or some local state drive). So for jimy.www.domain.com the Document root will be `D:/www` of the client machine ?

Or is there any other workaround ?

Comment: Why don't you have a local working copy of the repo (as you say on D:) and push to the repo (as you already have on M:) on the server?

Comment: @DanD. That would have 1 more step of syncing files on and D: and M:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, while git might be used on network shares, it is far from optimal -it needs to load both the .git files, and all the files from the network share to see what has changed.

Using network shares, you *might* mount folders from the server's side, however performance of this on server requests will be drastically worse, which increases your code-test-evaluate cycles from 5-10 seconds to ~10-30 seconds *each*. This is a performance (and psychological) penalty your developers will neither tolerate, nor can afford.

There are ways around this:

- Using a similar configuration, our solution was also having shell access to the server, and using git from the shell only; this allows for semi-instant git checkout / commit, and also for auxiliary server-side scripts, specifically for deployment, rollback, and unit testing.
- Another popular choice is having everyone work on fully local copies (by setting up a replica of the live environment in virtualbox), then committing their changes to the central repo

Hope this helps, comment if you need clarifications.

Comment: Most probably we will be opting the second suggestion. By the way thanks for the workaround of first suggestion.